# Is the 25 game suspension for Chris Davis too much?

Tags: rules, baseball, mlb, suspension

Chris Davis just got a 25 game suspension for violation of the MLB's drug program for use of Adderall. He had a medical exemption in the past, but for whatever reason did not have one this year.

I could see if it was a PED for a suspension like this, but for Adderall? It might give him better focus, but he clearly had a medical reason to take it. Per the MLB Drug Rules is there much flexibility when it comes to something like this, i.e., previous exemption?

Comment: This seems like an opinion question, and isn't appropriate for the SE system to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is the 25 game suspension for Chris Davis too much?

No. This is Chris Davis's second positive test<sub>[(1)](http://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/mlb/orioles/2014/09/12/chris-davis-suspended-25-games-use-amphetamines/15507459/)</sub>.

Section 7.B (below) of the MLB Joint Drug Agreement states that a second stimulant violation is a 25-game suspension<sub>[(2 - on p.22 of the MLB JDA document)](http://mlb.mlb.com/pa/pdf/jda.pdf)</sub>.

> [image: MLB JDA on Stimulant Violations]

Comment: I would have thought that the past therapeutic use exemption would have been taken into consideration, but I guess there really isn't much flexibility in the MLB Drug Agreement.

Comment: @JimmyGlenn the first test would have been outside the realm of the therapeutic use exemption as well.